# JavaScript - Get object property from element data

Tags: javascript, object, element

I'm wondering if that's possible to get object property from element data.

So let's say I have element:

```
<div data-item="objProp" class="test">test</div>
```

And js object:

```
var obj = {
objProp: true
}
```

I tried to:

```
var test = $('.test').data('item');
alert(obj.test);
```

So, yeah, is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want

```
alert(obj[test]);
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you. For some reason I though [] only refers to arrays. Thank you once again.

Comment: I'd recommend you to read [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_objects), that's a good documentation.

Comment: You've post the answer just 8 seconds faster ;)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/TSeAP/)**</kbd>

Try to use `[]`:

```
alert(obj[test]);
```