# Draw Table Using HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, parse-platform

I am trying to populate a table with data from a JavaScript query. Currently, the problem I am running into is that no table is created, and consequently, no data is displayed. A working version of this method can be viewed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775519/html-draw-table-using-innerhtml/%22here%22). Thanks!

```js
    // Initializes Parse
    // Defines Parse Object Array
    var object = {};

    // Defines Data Query
    var query = new Parse.Query("_User");

    query.find({

     success: function(results) {

      // Creates Table in Document
      var table = document.createElement("table");
      var row = table.insertRow(0);

      // Sets Table Attributes
      table.setAttribute("border", "1");
      table.setAttribute("width", "100%");

      // Loops Through Query
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i = i + 1) {

       // Stores Results
       var object = results[i];
       var text = object.get("firstName") + " " + object.get("lastName");
       var cell = row.insertCell(i);

       cell.setAttribute("align", "center");
       cell.appendChild(text);

      }

      document.getElementById("main").appendChild(table);

     },

     failure: function(error) {

      alert("Something Went Wrong");

     }

    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <!-- Destination -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First there was script anchors in the script, there is no need of that and it was making an error. I have corrected that in your snippet.

Comment: then you have to load the Parse library

Comment: Parse is all working fine, I omitted it from the code so one couldn't mess with my app data.

Comment: My code is pretty much exactly the same as the working code that is linked which is why I am so confused

Comment: you can use the debugger of your browser to see where there is a problem. And some errors may be displayed is the dev console.

Comment: There was no errors to be reported. Completely stumped on why the table is not created. The problem is with the table being created, not the data within it.

Comment: see my answer. You should provide functional examples to ease the work of helpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with how I appended the text. Instead of `cell.appendChild(text);`, it should have been `cell.textContext = text;`.

Here is the final code

```
// Initializes Parse (Purposely Omitted)


// Defines Parse Object Array
var object = {};

// Defines Data Query
var query = new Parse.Query("_User");

query.find ({

  success: function(results) {

    // Creates Table in Document
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);

    // Sets Table Attributes
    table.setAttribute("border", "1");
    table.setAttribute("width", "100%");

    // Loops Through Query
    for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i = i + 1) {

      // Stores Results
      var object = results[i];
      var text = object.get("firstName") + " " + object.get("lastName");
      var cell = row.insertCell(i);

      cell.setAttribute("align", "center");
      cell.textContent = text;

    }

  document.getElementById("main").appendChild(table);

  },

  failure: function(error) {

    alert("Something Went Wrong");

  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your code:

- object.get method does not exists, you can get properties with these ways:

  `object.propertyName or object["propertyName"]`

[JavaScript - Get object property from element data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563923/javascript-get-object-property-from-element-data)

- you can not use appendChild to insert a text node, you can use `textContent`
- errors are thrown on the console. if you had to use the debugger, put some breakpoints, you would have seen that problems.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging
[https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Outils/Débogueur](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Outils/D%C3%A9bogueur)

```js
var success= function(results) {

      // Creates Table in Document
      var table = document.createElement("table");
      var row = table.insertRow(0);

      // Sets Table Attributes
      table.setAttribute("border", "1");
      table.setAttribute("width", "100%");

      // Loops Through Query
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i = i + 1) {

       // Stores Results
       var object = results[i];
       var text = object.firstName+ " " + object["lastName"];
       var cell = row.insertCell(i);

       cell.setAttribute("align", "center");
       cell.textContent= text;

      }

          
  document.getElementById("main").appendChild(table);

}

datas= [
 { firstName:"f1",lastName:"n1"},
 { firstName:"f2",lastName:"n2"},
 { firstName:"f3",lastName:"n3"},
 { firstName:"f4",lastName:"n4"},
];
  
success(datas);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <!-- Destination -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Object.get method does exist through the Parse library. I figured it out by how the text was appended to the table. Thanks!